# How should the bias be initialized and regularized?

Tags: neural-network

I've read a couple of papers about kernel initialization and many papers mention that they use L2 regularization of the kernel (often with $\lambda = 0.0001$).

Does anybody do something different than initializing the bias with constant zero and not regularizing it?

### Kernel initialization papers

- Mishkin and Matas: [All you need is a good init](https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.06422)
- Xavier Glorot and Yoshua Bengio: [Understanding the difficulty of training deep feedforward neural networks](http://jmlr.org/proceedings/papers/v9/glorot10a/glorot10a.pdf)
- He et al: [Delving Deep into Rectifiers: Surpassing Human-Level Performance on ImageNet Classification](https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.01852)

Answer (score 22):

From the [Stanford CS231N Notes](http://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-2/):

> Initializing the biases. It is possible and common to initialize the
> biases to be zero, since the asymmetry breaking is provided by the
> small random numbers in the weights. For ReLU non-linearities, some
> people like to use small constant value such as 0.01 for all biases
> because this ensures that all ReLU units fire in the beginning and
> therefore obtain and propagate some gradient. However, it is not clear
> if this provides a consistent improvement (in fact some results seem
> to indicate that this performs worse) and it is more common to simply
> use 0 bias initialization.

In LSTMs it's common to initialize the biases to 1 - see for [example](http://www.jmlr.org/proceedings/papers/v37/jozefowicz15.pdf).